# How to count the number of anchor tags within a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to count the number of anchor tags present within a `div` element.
e.g.:

```
<div>
<a href="1" >1</a>
<a href="2" >2</a>
<a href="3" >3</a>
<a href="4" >4</a>
</div>
```

How many `<a>` tags?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
theDivElement.getElementsByTagName('a').length
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [HTML DOM getElementsByTagName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp) to get all "a" tags under an object.
To get the div you'de be better off giving it an ID and then use 
*getElementsByTagName*.

```js
var anchors = document.getElementById("thediv").getElementsByTagName("a");
alert("The Div has " + anchors.length + " links in it");
```

```html
<div id="thediv">
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 2</a>
  <a href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
```