# Count the number of links on Webpage?

Tags: php, html, dom

How to count the no of  links present on web page and it's should not count the google , linkdin , facebook , twitter page if page contains the social link.

Comment: You can count it based on `<a href=... >` tag to count the links... :)

Comment: You can count the number of anchor tags on the page.

Comment: [Similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086474/how-to-count-the-number-of-anchor-tags-within-a-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

This will tell you all `a` tags except the facebook link. Add the rest yourself :P

```
<script>
    $("a[href^='https://www.facebook.com']").remove();

    console.log(    document.body.getElementsByTagName('a').length)
</script>
```